# Angular service assignment does not preserve the state?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to understand how angular works. I have an standalone component `TestComponent` that receive `TestService` as an injection, this component call the method `this.testService.assign()`, later a `Guard` inject the `TestService` and call the method `reassign()` the value of the variable `inc` I expected to be 2 because it was set previously but I don't know if this behavior is normal. Could you please tell me how I can achieve that the value of the variable `inc` should be 2 when I call the method `reassign`

test.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrl: './test.component.scss'
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private testService: TestService) {
  }

  start() {
     this.testService.assign();
  }
}
```

test.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {

  private inc = 1;

  constructor() { }

  //Called from a Standalone component before the Guard
  assign() {
    this.inc = 2;
    console.log('FromComponent ' + this.inc);
  }

  //Called from a Guard
  reassign() {
    //The value here is 1 it should be 2
    console.log('FromGuard ' + this.inc);
    this.inc = 3;
  }

}
```

test.guard.ts

```
import {CanActivateFn, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {inject} from "@angular/core";
import {TestService} from "../../../shared/service/test.service";

export const TestGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
  const testService = inject(TestService);
  testService.reassign();
  return true;
};
```

The `start` method is called here, it init the cycle the `guard` is called later.
test.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="start()">
.
.
.
```

Output

```
FromComponent 2
FromGuard 1 <--- Should be 2?
```

Comment: Could you explain why it should be 2?

Comment: The only place I see the assignment is in reassign, which is called. assign is never called. right?

Comment: @vega My understanding is because is assigned previously by the standalone component before the Guard is called. Yes is being called I dont put the exact call in the code but in the output you can see it. It's calle from a form that invoke the method `start` of the `TestComponent`

Comment: Where is that code?

Comment: You should maybe add a console.log in the TestService constructor to check if maybe it's called twice. If it is, it means something is wrong with the way your modules are defined, and the problem isn't with the code you've shown but with the fact that Angular instantiated the same service twice. From there you can probably find existing questions to solve this problem (the answer will depend on your exact setup).

Comment: Where is your routing configuration? Where did you put the guard? Somehow you are refreshing the browser and losing state!

Comment: Make sure that you dont add TestService in any module's or conponent's providers array. This would make then create separate instance on service, which could result in behaviour you described in the post

Answer (score 0):

If your `TestGuard` is used to protect your `TestComponent`, then the guard will be the first who calls the service and you have `console.log` in `reassign` function before assignement, so it is 1, then you assign it to 3, then it comes to the component where in `ngOnInit` it is reassigned to 2 and logged again. If you want to understand your case better, log the value before and after assignement in each function, because the way you do it is not clear.